# Print multiple arrays with condition in foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays

Hi i need to print the names of $aSpelers and $aRugnummers when array $Posities of the $aSpelers is 'verdediger'

So for example: 
Janmaat 7 Verdediger 
de Vrij 3 Verdediger

So the first value of the array doesnt has to print out because it's not a 'verdediger'

Here are the arrays i have to use

```
$aSpelers = array('Cilessen', 'Janmaat', 'de Vrij' , 'Vlaar', 'Blind', 'de Jong', 'Sneijder');
$aRugnummers = array(1, 7, 3, 2, 5,8, 10 );
$Posities = array('doel', 'verdediging', 'verdediging', 'verdediging', 'verdediging','middenveld','middenveld');
```

I have to use a foreach loop this is what i have already

```
foreach()
{

}
```

Comment: You have to use a foreach? Why?

Comment: @Andreas Its for a exercise i need to use a foreach loop or a for loop

Comment: Where is 'verdediger' or whatever position being assigned to a player? they seem to be completely independant

Comment: see there is a big difference between for and foreach. Foreach in this case is hard, for on the other hand is easy. Easy enough that you should do your own exercise

Comment: for an exercice ? Try a little bit by yourself before asking us to do your homework ! Start by reading the documentation of foreach

Comment: I don't understand why you all give him answers. He has not done anything to even try. He didn't even finnish the only line of code he supplied in the question

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
for($i = 0;$i<count($aSpelers);$i++) {
  if($Posities[$i] == 'verdediging'){
    echo $aSpelers[$i]." ".$aRugnummers[$i]." ".$Posities[$i];
  }
  echo "<br />";
}
```

Output:

```
Janmaat 7 verdediging
de Vrij 3 verdediging
Vlaar 2 verdediging
Blind 5 verdediging
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this  use **for** loop

```
for($i=0;$i<count($aSpelers);$i++)
 {

   if($Posities[$i] == 'verdediging')
   {

   echo $aSpelers[$i].'   '.$aRugnummers[$i].'    '.$Posities.'<br/>';

   }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you need it with foreach**

I assume the players and their positions are only linked based on their indexes in the arrays. In that case try this:

```
$aSpelers = array('Cilessen', 'Janmaat', 'de Vrij' , 'Vlaar', 'Blind', 'de Jong', 'Sneijder');
$aRugnummers = array(1, 7, 3, 2, 5,8, 10 );
$Posities = array('doel', 'verdediging', 'verdediging', 'verdediging', 'verdediging','middenveld','middenveld');
foreach($aSpelers as $key=>$speler) {
    echo $speler.$aRugnummers[$key].$Posities[$key]."<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$aSpelers = array('Cilessen', 'Janmaat', 'de Vrij' , 'Vlaar', 'Blind', 'de Jong', 'Sneijder');
$aRugnummers = array(1, 7, 3, 2, 5,8, 10 );
$Posities = array('doel', 'verdediging', 'verdediging', 'verdediging', 'verdediging','middenveld','middenveld');

for ($i = 0; $i < count($aSpelers); $i++) {
    if($Posities[$i] == 'verdediging') {
        echo "{$aSpelers[$i]} {$aRugnummers[$i]} {$Posities[$i]} <br>";
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Janmaat 7 verdediging
de Vrij 3 verdediging
Vlaar 2 verdediging
Blind 5 verdediging
```

Comment: he said foreach not for

Comment: @Minzkraut Please take a look at his own posts comments. `@Andreas Its for a exercise i need to use a foreach loop or a for loop `

Comment: @Andreas yes sorry, my mistake. i didn't see that at first